# iphone simulator directory stucture

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

In the iphone simulator directory, I see folder based on version number, such as 3.2, 4.0.2, 4.2, and 4.3.2. I also see a User directory. My understanding is that depending on the version number, the simulator will install application in respective version directory.

However, I also see a User directory, when will the applications be installed in the user directory?

Comment: The user directory is not for applications. applications will never be installed there.

Comment: really, there is an Applications directory under User, and I saw some applications there.

Comment: I don't see applications there on my installation.

Comment: user iphone simulator, there is a user directory, under user directory, i see Applications directory, and under there, i see a lot of Guids with each Guid corresponding to an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the place where the iPhone simulator store its own data.